Android Studio 2024.1.1 - Gradle Project sync failed
I try to use Android Studio but  there is a problem since i downloaded it, the sync fail.
I always got the same Error messages :

"Could not move temporary workspace"
"java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException"

I tried to clean the project but i don't have this option in  the "Build" menu.
So i manually remove the caches folder but it didn't work.
I also uninstalled and reinstalled but it didn't work.
And for last i change the gradle version in "gradle-wrapper.properties" from 8.7 to 8.5 but 8.7 is the min version for my plugin.
Hope someone could help me.
Thanks in advance.

Which OS are you on? My best guess from your description would be that AS is installed in some access restricted directory and doesn't have the permission to move file to/from there. Have you tried starting AS with administrator rights?

Hi, thanks for your help. I'm on Windows 11. Yes, i already try to star AS with administrator right. AS is located in the "Program Files" repertory of my computer.
